# Symfony 1.4 sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable customization

Tags: image, file, generics, symfony1, upload

I am using the sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable widget for my users to upload images.

I would like to see if there's a way to alter the way it works be default. When a user is adding a "new" object, I would like for it to show a generic picture, and when it's an "edit" then it can show the existing pic. I tried writing a PHP conditional statement but that's not working for me because when it's a "new" item I can't pull the parameter "getPicture1" because it doesn't exist.

My widget currently:

```
$this->widgetSchema['picture1'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
    'label' => ' ',
    'file_src' => '/uploads/car/'.$this->getObject()->getPicture1(),
    'is_image' => true,
    'edit_mode' => true,
    'template' => '<div>%file%<br />%input%</div>',
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options (the second one is more easy).

**First option:** create your own `sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable` and extends the original.

In a file `lib/widget/myWidgetFormInputFileEditable.class.php`:

```
class myWidgetFormInputFileEditable extends sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable
{
  protected function getFileAsTag($attributes)
  {
    if ($this->getOption('is_image'))
    {
      if (false !== $src = $this->getOption('file_src'))
      {
        // check if the given src is empty of image (like check if it has a .jpg at the end)
        if ('/uploads/car/' === $src)
        {
          $src = '/uploads/car/default_image.jpg';
        }
        $this->renderTag('img', array_merge(array('src' => $src), $attributes))
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return $this->getOption('file_src');
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to call it:

```
$this->widgetSchema['picture1'] = new myWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
  'label'     => ' ',
  'file_src'  => '/uploads/car/'.$this->getObject()->getPicture1(),
  'is_image'  => true,
  'edit_mode' => true,
  'template'  => '<div>%file%<br />%input%</div>',
));
```

**Second option:** check if the object is new then use the default image.

```
$file_src = $this->getObject()->getPicture1();
if ($this->getObject()->isNew())
{
  $file_src = 'default_image.jpg';
}

$this->widgetSchema['picture1'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
  'label'     => ' ',
  'file_src'  => '/uploads/car/'.$file_src,
  'is_image'  => true,
  'edit_mode' => true,
  'template'  => '<div>%file%<br />%input%</div>',
));
```

Comment: Thanks j0k!!   You're a life saver.   The second option is more what I was going for but I didn't realize that you could write "if" statements in the form.class file.   Thanks again!